# Spark is ignoring bucketing setting for Hive table

Tags: apache-spark

I am working with a one terabyte size dataset on S3. The data is in Parquet files. After executing the following code there are many files created in each partition but not the right number (6).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode
val dates = List(201208, 201209)
spark.sqlContext.sql("use db")
dates.foreach { date =>

  val df = spark
    .sqlContext
    .sql("select * from db.orig_parquet_0 where departure_date_year_month_int=" + date)

  df.write.format("orc")
    .option("compression","zlib")
    .option("path","s3://s3-bucket/test_orc_opt_1")
    .sortBy("departure_date_year", "activity_date_int", "agency_continent")
    .partitionBy("departure_date_year_month_int")
    .bucketBy(6, "departure_date_year")
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .saveAsTable("db.test_orc_opt_1");
}
```

When I try to query it from Presto it throws the following exception:

```
Query 20180820_074141_00004_46w5b failed: Hive table 'db.test_orc_opt_1' is corrupt. The number of files in the directory (13) does not match the declared bucket count (6) for partition: departure_date_year_month_int=201208
```

Is there a way to enforce bucketing for Spark?

Spark version 2.3.1

Comment: Please check https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15300. Also what is the scheme of  orig_parquet_0?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
.bucketBy(6, "departure_date_year")
```

to

```
.bucketBy(13, "departure_date_year")
```

which version of spark you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Spark bucketing is different from Hive bucketing. Use hive to insert table instead of Spark.

Please look at page 42,

https://www.slideshare.net/databricks/hive-bucketing-in-apache-spark-with-tejas-patil

[image: Spark Bucket vs Hive Bucket]